# How to access and modify imported .css files in WordPress style.css file?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project to perform minor editing on WordPress website, but got stuck at this one. Please help me.

In WordPress style.css there is not much css code but imported files

```
/*Animate*/
@import url('css/animate.css');

/* Bootstrap */
@import url('css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* Responsive */
@import url('css/responsive.css');
```

How can I access these files and modify the CSS?

Comment: Are you trying to edit through the WordPress admin interface? From there, you can't see the files in the `css` folder. You will need to access the files directly on the server using FTP or SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going through the editor in the admin panel of the Wordpress then the only way to "edit" those files it to override their styles. You have to basically set a higher inheritance of what you are attempting to edit.

The only way to get to those files is to access the web server and if you are not able to get to the web server then you cannot edit the files.